# continously throws errors when running a load test in wso2esb

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

when ever concurrence user using my service at  a time its throwing errors i need to set any properties for multiple users at a time
But wso2ESB maintaining 1 billions transcation with EBAY but 
while i am sending morethan 5 its giving errors

```
 PassThroughHttpListener System may be unstable: HTTP ListeningIOReactor encountered a runtime exception : null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceResponse.start(SourceResponse.java:83)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler.responseReady(SourceHandler.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultNHttpServerConnection.produceOutput(DefaultNHttpServerConnection.java:223)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultServerIOEventDispatch.outputReady(DefaultServerIOEventDispatch.java:161)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.writable(BaseIOReactor.java:179)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:344)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:318)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:278)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:542)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

how can i avoid this to achive more flexibility in wso2esb
i am using wso2esb 4.6.0 and wso22dss 3.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a Pass-Through issue as filed in [[1]](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-1934). [ESB 4.7.0](http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-service-bus) is the latest version as of now and the fix is available with that.

Comment: it means i need to download 4.7.0 version to avoid this issue.when ever my mobile side client sending requests continuously just 1st request only processing remaining is not able to get parameters and giving null pointer exception in wso2dss

Comment: ESB 4.7.0 contains the fix. If you still need to run ESB 4.6.0, you need to apply the attached patch here https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-1934 to the code base and put the patched jar to the running setup. Hope this helps. Thanks!

Comment: thanx for replay k i will try and let u know..is this issue only in 4.6.0 or previous versions also

Comment: Yes, the issue is with 4.6.0, a pass-thru issue. In previous releases NHTTP was the default transport. You might be able to solve this issue (in 4.6.0) by switching to nhttp as well.