# Can we use Multiple Users at a time for one service in wso2 Esb

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

my client sending me single request that time my proxy processing the response well
whenever number of clients increasing my proxy went error 
means same service hit by number of client request with HTTP request 
my error like this

```
 PassThroughHttpListener System may be unstable: HTTP ListeningIOReactor encountered a runtime exception : null
java.lang.NullPointerException
   at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceResponse.start(SourceResponse.java:83)
   at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler.responseReady(SourceHandler.java:184)
   at org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultNHttpServerConnection.produceOutput(DefaultNHttpServerConnection.java:223)
   at org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultServerIOEventDispatch.outputReady(DefaultServerIOEventDispatch.java:161)
   at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.writable(BaseIOReactor.java:179)
   at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:344)
   at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:318)
   at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:278)
   at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)
   at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:542)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
 Can we handle number of clients in wso2esb for that i need to set any HTTP NOnBlocking Property
```

Comment: What version of ESB are you using?

Comment: using wso2esb 4.6.0 and wso2dss 3.0.0 .my issue parallel HTTP connections not taking giving transport errors

Comment: This has already been answered here[1].Pls use ESB 4.7.0.          [1] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17855685/continously-throws-errors-when-running-a-load-test-in-wso2esb